# decorations.markings: hiding the path behind

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations

I am drawing a chain (of the metal type) using the decorations.markings library but have a couple of problems:

1. I'd like to remove the path behind the chain. I can't set the color of the path to hide it because the chain will be in front of a shaded area and color changes.
2. Due to the tightness of the curve on the path, pairs of adjacent links aren't behaving well. I realize that this is due to the length of my two-link shape relative to the tightness of the curve. Is it possible to split the two-link shape into separate (i.e., shorter) shapes and draw them separately so they fit to the path more closely? How would I do that?

TIA, Dave

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,decoration={
    markings,% switch on markings
    mark=% actually add a mark
    between positions 0 and 1 step 12pt
    with
    {       
        \draw[red, very thick] (0pt,-2pt) -- ++(4pt,0) arc(-90:90:2pt) -- ++(-4pt,0pt) arc(90:270:2pt) -- cycle;
        \draw[red,very thick] (-8pt,0) -- (0pt,0);      
    }
    }]
    \draw[ultra thin, postaction={decorate}] (0,0) -- +(0,7.5) arc(180:90:1) -- +(2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\path` instead of `\draw`?

Comment: @percusse. Thank you: path gets rid of the line behind. The 'reasonably' complete solution below solves the problems with the links beautifully.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is 'reasonably' complete. The number of links is specified along with the overlap of consecutive links. The decoration 'does it's best' to provide a complete number of links along the path, but (as always with decorations), TeX maths is a bit inaccurate, so some parameter settings may produce unexpected output or errors.

Other customisations (not implemented here) include whether the initial link is a 'side' link (i.e., a straight line) or a 'front' link (i.e., the elongated "O"), and whether the first/last chain links should be *centered* on the start/end of the path or left/right alinged (as it is here).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, decorations.markings}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{chain links}{prepare}{
\state{prepare}[width=0,next state=shift, 
  persistent precomputation={
    \def\chainstate{0}
    \ifpgflinkcentered
        \def\pgflinkshift{0pt}
          \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\pgflinklength{\pgfdecoratedpathlength/
            \pgflinkcount+\pgflinkoverlap}
      \else
        \def\pgflinkshift{\pgflinklength/2}
          \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\pgflinklength{(\pgfdecoratedpathlength
        -\pgflinkoverlap)/\pgflinkcount+\pgflinkoverlap}
      \fi
      \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\pgflinkheight{\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}
  }]{}
\state{shift}[width=\pgflinkshift, next state=link]{}
\state{link}[width=\pgflinklength-\pgflinkoverlap,
  persistent precomputation={\pgfmathsetmacro\chainstate{int(1-\chainstate}}]    
    {\pgfchainlinkdrawlink}
\state{final}{
  \pgfmathsetmacro\chainstate{int(1-\chainstate)}
  \pgfchainlinkdrawlink
 }
}
\def\pgfchainlinkdrawlink{%
  \ifcase\chainstate
    \path [every chain link/.try]
      (-\pgflinklength/2, 0) -- (\pgflinklength/2, 0);
  \else
    \path [every chain link/.try]
      (0, \pgflinkheight/2) --
      (\pgflinklength/2-\pgflinkheight/2, \pgflinkheight/2)
          arc (90:-90:\pgflinkheight/2) --
          (-\pgflinklength/2+\pgflinkheight/2, -\pgflinkheight/2)
          arc (270:90:\pgflinkheight/2) -- cycle;
    \fi
}
\newif\ifpgflinkcentered
\pgfkeys{/pgf/decoration/.cd,
  link count/.store in=\pgflinkcount,
  link overlap/.store in=\pgflinkoverlap,
  center links/.code=\csname pgflinkcentered#1\endcsname,
  center links/.default=true,
  link count=20,
  link overlap=2pt,
  center links=false,
}
\tikzset{%
  every chain link/.style={
    line cap=round,
    very thick,
    draw=red,
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={chain links, amplitude=4pt}]
\path [postaction={decorate}] 
  (0,0) -- ++(0,2) arc(180:90:1) -- ++(2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! This is really humbling - I have much to learn! And I can learn a lot from your code. Thank you very much. :)